# how to use gson.fromJson with generic type T

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to build a generic method which will call any of an APIs specific endpoints, each of which returns its own object type.

```
private  <T> T callApi(String endpoint) {
  T responseSuccessObject = null;
  String responseBody = ...
  responseSuccessObject = (T) gson.fromJson(responseBody, responseSuccessObject.getClass());
}
```

The above does not work (fails with null pointer exception)

Also tried this:

```
private  <T> T callApi(String endpoint) {
  T responseSuccessObject = (T) new Object();
  String responseBody = ...
  responseSuccessObject = (T) gson.fromJson(responseBody, responseSuccessObject.getClass());
}
```

Which fails with this:

```
com.xx.AuthResponseModel is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @58bd8c78)
```

I have seen a possible solution by passing in a dummy object of the required class, but this is not an ideal option, as it would require adding and passing the type parameter down a long line of calls.

Not sure how this would work.

```
private  <T> T callApi(Class<T> type, String endpoint) {
  T responseSuccessObject = null;
  String responseBody = ...
  responseSuccessObject = (T) gson.fromJson(responseBody, ?);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is just

```
private  <T> T callApi(Class<T> type, String endpoint) {
  T responseSuccessObject = null;
  String responseBody = ...
  responseSuccessObject = (T) gson.fromJson(responseBody, type);
}
```

If there were a solution that avoided passing along the `Class` object, Gson would already use it.  There isn't.  To learn more, research [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How do I call it? I tried callApi(Myclass.type, endpoint) and callApi(Myclass, endpoint) and callApi(myclass.getClass(), endpoint), I cant think of other variations.

Comment: You call it as `callApi(MyClass.class, endpoint)`.

Comment: Note that if for one of your callers `T` is a parameterized type such as `List<MyClass>`, then you would need to change `Class` to [Gson's `TypeToken`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) because due to type erasure (as mentioned in this answer) a `Class<List<MyClass>>` would be `Class<List>` at runtime. (Note that you can obtain a `Class<List<MyClass>>` only through unsafe casts anyways; and these casts are really unsafe)